# How to delete a sign from a key in a nested python dictionary with lists in it?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, key

I have a data dump with n JSON objects of the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : {"$numberLong" : "734702956751294464" }, 
    "created_at" : "Mon May 23 11:10:09 +0000 2016", 
    "entities" : {
        "user_mentions" : [ { 
            "name" : "Thierry Zoller", 
            "id" : 15589731, 
            "indices" : [ 3, 17 ], 
            "screen_name" : "thierryzoller", 
            "id_str" : "15589731" 
            } ], 
        "media" : [ { 
            "source_status_id" : { "$numberLong" : "734677772963041280" }, 
            "url" : "XXXXX", 
            "source_user_id_str" : "15589731", 
            "source_user_id" : 15589731, 
            "id" : { "$numberLong" : "734677772703019008" }, 
            "type" : "photo", 
            "id_str" : "734677772703019008" 
            } ], 
        "hashtags" : [] }, 
    "favorited" : false, 
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : null, 
    "extended_entities" : { 
        "media" : [ { 
            "source_status_id" : { "$numberLong" : "734677772963041280" }, 
            "media_url_https" : "XXXXX", 
            "url" : "XXXXX", 
            "source_user_id_str" : "15589731", 
            "source_user_id" : 15589731,
            "indices" : [ 113, 136 ], 
            "display_url" : "pic.twitter.com/nO9tw2O4eY", 
            "id" : { "$numberLong" : "734677772703019008" }, 
            }]
        }
}
```

I want to delete the "$"in the "$numberLong" key.

The following code eliminates the "$" of keys outside the lists:

```
def rec_key_replace(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        return {key.replace('$', ''): rec_key_replace(val) for key, val in obj.items()}
    return obj
```

How can I extend this function so that it is possible to delete all "$" from keys, even if they are in nested lists (It could be that a list also contains other lists etc)?

Thank you.

Comment: You made it recursive but you only handle the `Mapping` type case. You need to recurse through other objects and lists in that tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to run through the data structure and replace dict keys starting with `'$'`.

1. If the current object is a list, iterate through it recursing through the contained items.
2. If the object is a dictionary, update the keys starting with the `'$'` sign by setting a new key with the `'$'` character *stripped* on the *popped* value of the old key, then recurse through the dictionary values to uncover nested dicts or lists. Values that are strings are simply returned as is.

---

```
from pprint import pprint

def replace_keys(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [replace_keys(x) for x in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k.lstrip('$') if k.startswith('$') else k: replace_keys(x) 
                                                       for k, v in obj.items()}
    else:
        return obj

new_obj = replace_keys(obj)
pprint(new_obj)
```

---

```
{'_id': {'numberLong': '734702956751294464'},
 'created_at': 'Mon May 23 11:10:09 +0000 2016',
 'entities': {'hashtags': [],
              'media': [{'id': {'numberLong': '734677772703019008'},
                         'id_str': '734677772703019008',
                         'source_status_id': {'numberLong': '734677772963041280'},
                         'source_user_id': 15589731,
                         'source_user_id_str': '15589731',
                         'type': 'photo',
                         'url': 'XXXXX'}],
              'user_mentions': [{'id': 15589731,
                                 'id_str': '15589731',
                                 'indices': [3, 17],
                                 'name': 'Thierry Zoller',
                                 'screen_name': 'thierryzoller'}]},
 'extended_entities': {'media': [{'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/nO9tw2O4eY',
                                  'id': {'numberLong': '734677772703019008'},
                                  'indices': [113, 136],
                                  'media_url_https': 'XXXXX',
                                  'source_status_id': {'numberLong': '734677772963041280'},
                                  'source_user_id': 15589731,
                                  'source_user_id_str': '15589731',
                                  'url': 'XXXXX'}]},
 'favorited': 'false',
 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': 'null'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import re

j = {'_id': {'$numberLong': '734702956751294464'}, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, 'created_at': 'Mon May 23 11:10:09 +0000 2016', 'extended_entities': {'media': [{'id': {'$numberLong': '734677772703019008'}, 'url': 'XXXXX', 'source_status_id': {'$numberLong': '734677772963041280'}, 'media_url_https': 'XXXXX', 'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/nO9tw2O4eY', 'source_user_id': 15589731, 'indices': [113, 136], 'source_user_id_str': '15589731'}]}, 'favorited': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'media': [{'id': {'$numberLong': '734677772703019008'}, 'url': 'XXXXX', 'source_status_id': {'$numberLong': '734677772963041280'}, 'type': 'photo', 'source_user_id': 15589731, 'id_str': '734677772703019008', 'source_user_id_str': '15589731'}], 'user_mentions': [{'id': 15589731, 'screen_name': 'thierryzoller', 'name': 'Thierry Zoller', 'indices': [3, 17], 'id_str': '15589731'}]}}

jStr = json.dumps(j)


for x in re.findall("""{["']\$[^"']*["':]""", jStr):
    jStr = jStr.replace(x, re.sub('\$', '', x))

print(jStr)
```